# jQuery how to check two array elements belongs to same array or not

Tags: jquery

i am new to jQuery as well as programming, how can i check whether two array elements belong to same array. I did this.. but its not working

```
var blackCoins = ["&#9818;", "&#9819;", "&#9820;", "&#9821;", "&#9822;", "&#9823;"];
var whiteCoins = ["&#9812;", "&#9813;", "&#9814;", "&#9815;", "&#9816;", "&#9817;"];
var buffer = $("myselector1").text();
var storeBuffer = $("#myselector2").text();
        var flag = 0;           
        if ($.inArray(buffer, whiteCoins) > -1  &&  $.inArray(storeBuffer, whiteCoins) > -1){                        
                flag = 1;
        }
        else if($.inArray(buffer, blackCoins) > -1  &&  $.inArray(storeBuffer, blackCoins) > -1) {
                flag = 1;
        }           
}
```

i can give more information if needed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JQuery .InArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) this function should help you out.

Use this in a && combination and you'll get your answer.

```
var blackCoins = ["&#9818;", "&#9819;", "&#9820;", "&#9821;", "&#9822;", "&#9823;"];
var whiteCoins = ["&#9812;", "&#9813;", "&#9814;", "&#9815;", "&#9816;", "&#9817;"];

function getCoinColor(coin) {
    var inBlack = $.inArray(coin, blackCoins);
    var inWhite = $.inArray(coin, whiteCoins);

    if (inBlack > -1) {
        return "black";
    }

    if (inWhite > -1) {
        return "white";
    }
}

function canKill(selectedCoin, targetCoin) {
    return getCoinColor(selectedCoin) != getCoinColor(targetCoin);
}


var targetCoin = "&#9818;";
var selectedCoin = "&#9821;";

var killable = canKill(selectedCoin, targetCoin);

if (killable) {
    alert("Killed it!");
}
else {
    alert("Can't kill your own kind!");
}​
```

I tried to write it as easy to understand as possible. I know there are a few ways to shorten it.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VHE9w/)

Comment: Hey i edited the code, just like you said. still its not working. Maybe i am doing something wrong.

Comment: I added a rework of your code. As far as I can understand the question.

Comment: Maybe you realized it that the strings are ascii characters for chess program. Would it make any difference? Actually i want to show that a white coin cant kill another white coin and same with black coins.

Comment: Seeing that there is a difference in ascii between white and black coins makes it even simpler. I'll edit my code.. just a sec.

Comment: I checked using alert(), the $.inArray() is not being recognized by jQuery. No console Errors. once check this [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/87374848/Blog/index.htm)

Comment: Thanks, here is the corrected [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/4ju3h/24/)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the same check twice, so put that check in a function:

```
function isWhiteCoin(color) {
  switch (color) {
    case "&#9812;":
    case "&#9813;":
    case "&#9814;":
    case "&#9815;":
    case "&#9816;":
    case "&#9817;": return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Now you can just call the function twice:

```
var flag=0;
var preRefColor = $("#check").text();
var thisColor = $(this).text();
if (isWhiteCoin(preRefColor) && isWhiteCoin(thisColor)) {
  flag = 1;
}
```

Comment: Hi, i understand the solution now, but it is not working. The problem is the same as @Kyorcode solution. The variables are not being equal to those strings. It may be because of ASCII characters.

Comment: @venkateshwar: I see, that's not the actual text in your element. Use the `html` methods instead of the `text` function to get the HTML code in the element, or use character codes instead of HTML entities when checking the values, i.e. `"&#9812;"` becomes `"\u2654"`.

Answer (score 0):

Something is strange about how you get the element to check - because of this:

```
$("#check").attr("id");
```

The attribute "id" of $('#check') will return "check"... what are you trying to do?

I assume we have a valid selector, then the answer would be:

```
  var flag=0;            
  var whiteCoins = ["&#9812;", "&#9813;", "&#9814;", "&#9815;", "&#9816;", "&#9817;"];
  var mytext = $('#myselector').text();

  if($.inArray(mytext, whiteCoins) > -1){
    flag=1;
  }
```

What I don't get from your code is if you maybe are checking two different elements against your array. From your code it is not clear what $(this) is. If you are checking two selectors and one of them is $(this), use this:

```
  var flag=0;            
  var whiteCoins = ["&#9812;", "&#9813;", "&#9814;", "&#9815;", "&#9816;", "&#9817;"];
  var mytext1 = $('#myselector1').text();
  var mytext2 = $(this).text();
  if($.inArray(mytext1, whiteCoins) > -1 && $.inArray(mytext2, whiteCoins) > -1){
    flag=1;
  }
```

Comment: yes it will return "check". Actually i haven't provided the full code here. Because i am having trouble in this part. I edited the question. Please inform me if it is still not clear.